# Detect remote charset in php

Tags: php, regex, encoding, preg-match

I would like to determine a remote page's encoding through detection of the *Content-Type* header tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=XXXXX" />
```

if present.

I retrieve the remote page and try to do a regex to find the required setting if present.
I am still learning hence the problem below...
Here is what I have:

```
    $EncStart = 'charset=';
    $EncEnd = '" \/\>';
    preg_match( "/$EncStart(.*)$EncEnd/s", $RemoteContent, $RemoteEncoding );
    echo = $RemoteEncoding[ 1 ];
```

The above does indeed echo the name of the encoding but it does not know where to stop so it prints out the rest of the line then most of the rest of the remote page in my test.
Example: When testing a remote russian page it printed:

> windows-1251" />
>   rest of page ....

Which means that `$EncStart` was okay, but the `$EncEnd` part of the regex failed to stop the matching. This meta header usually ends in 3 different possibility after the name of the encoding.

```
"> | "/> | " />
```

I do not know weather this is usable to satisfy the end of the maching and if yes how to escape it. I played with different ways of doing it but none worked.

Thank you in advance for lending a hand.

Comment: Don't use a regular expression for this. Use a real HTML parser, and don't forget that HTTP headers that specify the encoding will trump anything the document claims.

Comment: You should follow the order of precedence (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510868#2510931).

Comment: David, I've downloaded the [Simple HTML Dom Parser] and will look at it, but it seems a bit much for my current needs with this issue (unless it proves to be quick to learn and implement). will also look at the HTTP headers as well. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Gumbo, I am reading and learning, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a question mark to your pattern to make it non-greedy (and there's also no need of 's')

```
preg_match( "/charset=\"(.+?)\"/", $RemoteContent, $RemoteEncoding );
echo $RemoteEncoding[ 1 ];
```

note that this won't handle `charset = "..."` or `charset='...'` and many other combinations.

Comment: That's what I needed. The only issue with your regex is that you allowed for a ["] after the [=] where there are none. After Taking that out with its backslash, it worked as required with a few examples. Keeping your note in mind as I look at the other suggestions as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). With it, you can easily find the charset from the head without resorting to cumbersome regexes. But as David already commented, you should also examine [the headers](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) for the same information and prioritize it if found.

Tested example:

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$source = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
$dom = str_get_html($source);
$meta = $dom->find('meta[http-equiv=content-type]', 0);
$src_charset = substr($meta ->content, stripos($meta ->content, 'charset=') + 8);

foreach ($http_response_header as $header) {
    @list($name, $value) = explode(':', $header, 2);
    if (strtolower($name) == 'content-type') {
        $hdr_charset = substr($value, stripos($value, 'charset=') + 8);
        break;
    }
}

var_dump(
    $hdr_charset,
    $src_charset
);
```

Comment: Also, downloaded Simple HTML Dom Parser and looking into that as well.
thank you for the suggestion,