# Spanish characters are incorrect

Tags: php, html, curl

I downloaded a page with cURL and parsed the html with the "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser".
The issue is when it displays the outer html of the element, the Spanish characters are incorrect.
For example:

The original text

> la puja por la compra de los derechos de publicación ha sido la más
>   reñida del año.

The displayed text

> la puja por la compra de los derechos de publicaciÃ³n ha sido la mÃ¡s
>   reÃ±ida del aÃ±o.

What would cause the letters to changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that because it's appearing as multiple characters in the output this is occuring because you're trying to display some multi-byte UTF8 characters in a single-byte charset (probably ISO-8859-1).

Have a look at [this blog post](http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php/) that I wrote a while ago which should talk you through all of the potential problem areas.

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect Character encoding - ensure that the encoding throughout is consistent, I would suggest UTF-8

Comment: The correct answer, but doesn't do me any good since you do not describe how to ensure it with cURL

Answer (score 0):

U have to determine what is the encoding of downloaded page and then (by iconv for example) convert it to your encoding.

See [PHP: Convert curl_exec output to UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510868/php-convert-curl-exec-output-to-utf8)